# Spring Boot Admin Server and Client in the same application

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am using spring boot 2.5.1 with Java 11.

I am trying to create a **SpringBoot Admin Server** and **Client** in the same application, however when I start it, I get the following error in the console.

Ref: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin

**Error**

> Failed to register application as Application(name=PowWow,
> managementUrl=http://localhost:8085/actuator,
> healthUrl=http://localhost:8085/actuator/health,
> serviceUrl=http://localhost:8085/) at spring-boot-admin
> ([http://localhost:8085/instances]): 401 : [no body]. Further attempts
> are logged on DEBUG level

I have the following code in the Spring Boot application:

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8085
spring.application.name=PowWow
logging.file.name=powwow-logfile.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=3
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=5MB
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8085
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.health.show-details=always
```

**PowWowApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAdminServer
public class PowWowApplication {
```

**More info**

I can access the following url, but it does not load the application: http://localhost:8085/applications

[image]

**Question**

Do you know why the application is not being registered? Is it because you cannot have a `spring-boot-admin-starter-server` and a `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` in the same application?

**More info**

I realised that the application.properties has:

```
web.access.username=user
web.access.password=password
```

So I also add the following to allow the client access:

```
spring.boot.admin.client.username=user
spring.boot.admin.client.password=password
```

This removes the above error, i.e. there is no longer a 401 error when starting the server, but the application console reports that the server is down:

[image]

Console log: No Errors

http://localhost:8085/actuator/health  {"status":"UP"}

However, the details show there is a 401.

[image]

Comment: I have partially fixed the issue. I realised I have the following `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password` set. So if i set the `spring.boot.admin.client.username` and `spring.boot.admin.client.password` to match, it allows access, i.e. I no longer get the 401 error. However, the admin console reports that the application is down, the console shows: `ApplicationRegistrator       : Application registered itself as 2438ebd67f8a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by adding `/actuator/**` to the following:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/soapWS/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```